# How to use leaflet-extra/leaflet-providers with ngx-leaflet?

Tags: angular5, ngx-leaflet

How can I use `leaflet-extra/leaflet-providers` with `ngx-leaflet`. A simple example would be nice. I installed leaflet, @types/leaflet, ngx-leaflet, leaflet-providers, @types/leaflet-providers, but I cannot figure out how exactly to link ngx-leaflet with tileLayer.providers('ProviderId'). there should be an `.addTo(???map???)` call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the map reference, you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#getting-a-reference-to-the-map

There's also a guide with a bunch of examples of how to integrate Leaflet plugins located here: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-plugins

It sounds like with this example, you would use the providers plugin to create layers that you'd add to the layers array you are providing to the `leafletLayers` input binding or the `leafletLayersControl` input binding.

You'd just need to create the layers and add them to the appropriate array or object.

If you can provide some more specific example code I can give you more detail.

Comment: For some reason the `import { provider } from 'leaflet-providers'` does not import provider function. I followed the examples at https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-plugins and imported leaflet-providers.js with `import { tileLayer } from 'leaflet'; import 'leaflet-providers'` and it worked. Thanks.